# Simplify nested subselects containing aggregates

Tags: sql, nested, aggregate-functions, subquery

I'm trying to select all commission data for one of the invoice that will pay commissions to the highest number of sales people.  (Multiple commissions can be paid for each invoice.)  I have only the CommissionReport table, which contains commissions for each sales person for each invoice.

```
invoice_number     salesperson_id    commission_amt
----------------   ----------------  ----------------
            1001   Bob                          30.00
            1002   Alison                       64.50
            1002   Charlie                     110.25
```

This code works fine, but my subconcious is screaming that I don't need to nest subselects three deep. Can someone please straighten me out?

```
select

    invoice_number,
    salespeson_id,
    commission_amt  

from

    CommissionReport CR

    join

    (   select    top 1 invoice_number
        from      CommissionReport CR2
        group by  CR2.invoice_number
        having    count(*) = 

        (   select    max(CR3.cnt)
            from      

            (   select    invoice_number,
                          cnt = count(*)
                from      CommissionReport CR4
                group by  invoice_number
            ) CR3

        )

    ) CR2 on CR2.invoice_number = CR.invoice_number
```

Thanks very much in advance.

Scott

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't understand the requirements and this is my first query in Mssql... but check if this works:

```
select cr.invoice_number, cr.salesperson_id, cr.commission_amt  
from CommissionReport CR
where cr.invoice_number in (
    select top 1 invoice_number
    from CommissionReport CR2
    group by CR2.invoice_number
    order by count(*) desc
)
```

Comment: Apparently you DID understand the requirements, and you nailed the code.  This does exactly what I wanted.  Thanks very much.

Comment: Looks like you changed your mind about setting this answer as correct (yes, stackoverflow sold you out :P). Was there something wrong with the query?

Comment: No, nothing wrong. Your code works fine.  Just wanted to see if anybody else had anything to say on the matter.  I guess not.  I'll mention that some SQL coders might have suggested putting the subselect in a join rather than the where clause.  Actually that's the way I prefer - maybe it doesn't matter.  Thanks again for your solution.